# How can i use the data from Hbase to visualize using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hbase

This is my query for a optimum solution to my case. I have some tables in HBase in a remote computer. I am using Putty to scan the tables for data. I want to use those data for visualization using d3.js. My question is whether there is any better way to use those data for front end? Right now I am just using the data from putty to write to a csv file and using that. That is reducing the dynamic nature of my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use HBase thrift interface, or HBase REST interface to query you date from you javascript. Thrift solution is more lightweight and faster then REST.

[Here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi) you can find documentation on HBase Thrift interface, and [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-use-the-apache-hbase-rest-interface-part-1/) is a nice Cloudera blog post on HBase REST.

Hope this will help. Good luck.